# CSS3: Center Text (content) in div:before

Tags: html, css

I wrote some code to create a layover with some text. Now I have two problems:

1) I want to center the text.
2) I want to make the layover to be a link.

As I am a CSS newbie, I hope you can give me any advice!

Best regards!

```css
.hover_div {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.hover_div img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.hover_div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hover_div:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.hover_div:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}

.hover_div:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Elektro" class="hover_div">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code in the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvxo7fn5/

I've added the following lines to the `:before`:

```
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
margin-top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Basically, `text-align: center;` of course centers the text horizontally. However, an `absolute` positioned div has no width, which is why I added the `width: 100%`. Next you need to center it vertically. The `margin-top: 50%;` moves the div 50% of the height of the parent div. `transform: translateY(-50%)` moves the div back 50% of the height of the div itself. This aligns it in the center of the parent. (50% of parent height - 50% height of child div).

You also mentioned wanting it to be a link. This can be achieved by simply replacing the `<div>` with a `<a>` and adding `display: block;` to your `.hover_div` class. This gives it the properties a div would also have.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Update the **:hover** style as below.

```
.hover_div:hover:before 
{
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it link by replacing `<div>` with `<a>`.

```css
.hover_div {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.hover_div img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.hover_div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hover_div:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.hover_div:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}

.hover_div:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-content="Elektro" class="hover_div">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text can be centered by adding `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

Pseudo elements like :after and :before cannot be accessed from the DOM. So a link can't be made out of it.

```css
.hover_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.hover_div img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.hover_div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hover_div:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hover_div:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hover_div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Elektro" class="hover_div">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hover_div {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.hover_div img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.hover_div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    
}

.hover_div:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
}
.hover_div:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}

.hover_div:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Elektro" class="hover_div">
   <a href="link here"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't center the text - it just pushes it down from the top 50%;